# How to pass a parameter to query method of service class in Angular?

Tags: angular

This part of code generated by jHipster.

invoice.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'jhi-invoice',
    templateUrl: './invoice.component.html'
})

export class InvoiceComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {


  loadAll() {
        this.invoiceService
            .query({
            page: this.page - 1,
            size: this.itemsPerPage,
            sort: this.sort()
        })
        .subscribe(
            (res: HttpResponse<IInvoice[]>) =>  this.paginateInvoices(res.body, res.headers),
            (res: HttpErrorResponse) => this.onError(res.message)
        );
}

 ngOnInit() {
       this.loadAll();
       this.accountService.identity().then(account => {
       this.currentAccount = account;
       });
       this.registerChangeInInvoices();
   }
```

}

invoice.service.ts

```
@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })
    export class InvoiceService {
    public resourceUrl = SERVER_API_URL + 'api/invoices';

    constructor(protected http: HttpClient) {}    

    find(id: number): Observable<EntityResponseType> {
        return this.http
           .get<IInvoice>(`${this.resourceUrl}/${id}`, { observe: 'response' })
           .pipe(map((res: EntityResponseType) =>   this.convertDateFromServer(res)));
}

    query(req?: any): Observable<EntityArrayResponseType> {
        const options = createRequestOption(req);
        return this.http
            .get<IInvoice[]>(this.resourceUrl, { params: options, observe: 'response' })
            .pipe(map((res: EntityArrayResponseType) => this.convertDateArrayFromServer(res)));
    }
}
```

This code allows me to get all invoices, but I want to pass `client_id` to select only invoices for that client. Please help to implement this feature.

Comment: Firstly desingn your endpoint. In my opninion, the easiest way is to add a field client_id in your query. Or you can create in your endpoint server new route, for example 'api/invoices/user/{user_id}/' and requests to this route.

Comment: Roman , do You mean next ? :

loadAll(number: client_Id) {
this.invoiceService
            .query({
                page: this.page - 1,
                size: this.itemsPerPage,
                sort: this.sort()
                number:client_id
            })
}

Comment: wrote a snippet in example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use in query new parameter.

```
load(number: client_id) {
        this.invoiceService
            .query({
            page: this.page - 1,
            size: this.itemsPerPage,
            sort: this.sort(),
            client_id: client_id
        })
        .subscribe(...);
}
```